# Why does this ratio of sums of square roots equal $1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{4+2\sqrt2}=\cot\frac\pi{16}$ for any natural number $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, trigonometry, summation, fractions

Why is the following function $f(n)$ constant for any natural number $n$? 
$$f(n)=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n^2+2n}\sqrt{\sqrt{2n+2}+{\sqrt{n+1+\sqrt k}}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n^2+2n}\sqrt{\sqrt{2n+2}-{\sqrt{n+1+\sqrt k}}}}=1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{4+2\sqrt2}=\cot {\frac{\pi}{16}}.$$

I've been asking the following question at MSE:

Simplify $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{2499}\sqrt{10+{\sqrt{50+\sqrt{k}}}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{2499}\sqrt{10-{\sqrt{50+\sqrt{k}}}}}.$$

[Simplify $\left({\sum_{k=1}^{2499}\sqrt{10+{\sqrt{50+\sqrt{k}}}}}\right)\left({\sum_{k=1}^{2499}\sqrt{10-{\sqrt{50+\sqrt{k}}}}}\right)^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460331/simplify-left-sum-k-12499-sqrt10-sqrt50-sqrtk-right-left)

I've just got the following result:$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{2499}\sqrt{10+{\sqrt{50+\sqrt k}}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{2499}\sqrt{10-{\sqrt{50+\sqrt k}}}}=1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{4+2\sqrt2}.$$

**Proof**: Suppose that $\sum$ represents $\sum_{k=1}^{2499}$. Let the numerator and the denominator be $A$ and $B$ respectively. Letting $a_k=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{50+\sqrt k}}, b_k=\sqrt{10-\sqrt{50+\sqrt k}}$, we can represent $A, B$ as $A=\sum a_k, B=\sum b_k.$ Letting $p_k=\sqrt{50+\sqrt k}$ and $q_k=\sqrt{50-\sqrt k}$, since ${p_k}^2+{q_k}^2=10^2$ and $p_k\gt0, q_k\gt0$, there exists a real number $0\lt x_k\lt \frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $p_k=10\cos x_k, q_k=10\sin x_k$. Then, we get $$a_k=\sqrt{10+10\cos x_k}=\sqrt{10+10\left(2{\cos^2{\frac{x_k}{2}}}-1\right)}=\sqrt{20}\cos \frac{x_k}{2},$$$$b_k=\sqrt{10-10\cos x_k}=\sqrt{10-10\left(1-2{\sin^2{\frac{x_k}{2}}}\right)}=\sqrt{20}\sin \frac{x_k}{2}.$$

Then, since $\sum a_k=\sum a_{2500-k}$, let's consider $a_{2500-k}$.$$a_{2500-k}=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{50+\sqrt{(50+\sqrt k)(50-\sqrt k)}}}=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{50+{p_kq_k}}}=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{50+100\cos {x_k}\sin {x_k}}}=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{50(\cos {x_k}+\sin {x_k})^2}}=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{50}\cdot\sqrt2\sin \left(x_k+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}=\sqrt{10+10\cdot2\cos \left(\frac{x_k}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\sin \left(\frac{x_k}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\right)}=\sqrt{10\left(\cos \left(\frac{x_k}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{x_k}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right)^2}=\sqrt {10}\left(\cos \left(\frac{x_k}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{x_k}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right)=\frac{\left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right)a_k+\left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right)b_k}{\sqrt2}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt2+1}{2\sqrt2}}a_k+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt2-1}{2\sqrt2}}b_k.$$ Hence, $$A=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt2+1}{2\sqrt2}}A+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt2-1}{2\sqrt2}}B.$$
So, the proof is completed with $$\frac AB=1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{4+2\sqrt2}. $$

After a while, I got the following theorem in the same way as above.

**Theorem**: For any natural number $n$, $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n^2+2n}\sqrt{\sqrt{2n+2}+{\sqrt{n+1+\sqrt k}}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n^2+2n}\sqrt{\sqrt{2n+2}-{\sqrt{n+1+\sqrt k}}}}=1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{4+2\sqrt2}=\cot {\frac{\pi}{16}}.$$

Note that the case $n=49$ in this theorem is the question at the top.

I was surprised to get this theorem. Here is my question.

**Question**: Why is the function $f(n)$ constant for any natural number $n$? How can we explain this theorem in a geometrical aspect? Is there any *geometrical background*?

My question is about the background of this equation, and about the reason, not about the proof of it. This theorem has been already proved. Though I've already proved it, I wonder why it is constant.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Note that you can post your proof for case $n=49$ as an answer to your own question (the otherone) and accept it so that it gets some kind of closure

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: Thanks. I'll do so.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

$\frac {\cos (a+b) + \cos (a - b)}{\sin (a+b) + \sin (a -b)} = cotan (a)$ is independent of $b$.

In particular, with $a = \frac \pi {16}$, $\frac{\cos x + \cos (\frac \pi 8 - x)}{\sin x + \sin (\frac \pi 8 - x)}$ is independant of $x$.

Since $\cos(4(\frac \pi 8 - x)) = \sin(4x)$ and $\sin(4(\frac \pi 8 - x)) = \cos(4x)$, after multiplying the angle by $4$, those will look quite the same.

So, expressing everyone in terms of $\cos (4x)$ and $\sin (4x)$, you get the similar looking expressions (valid for $x \in [0 ; \frac \pi 8]$):

$\cos x = \sqrt{\frac 1 2 + \sqrt{\frac {1+ \cos(4x)}8}} \\
\sin x = \sqrt{\frac 1 2 - \sqrt{\frac {1+ \cos(4x)}8}} \\
\cos (\frac \pi 8 -x) = \sqrt{\frac 1 2 + \sqrt{\frac {1+ \sin(4x)}8}} \\
\sin (\frac \pi 8 -x) = \sqrt{\frac 1 2 - \sqrt{\frac {1+ \sin(4x)}8}} \\
$

Next, let $u = \cos(4x)^2$, you obtain that

$$\frac {\sqrt{\frac 1 2 + \sqrt{\frac {1+ \sqrt u}8}} + \sqrt{\frac 1 2 + \sqrt{\frac {1+ \sqrt{1-u}}8}}}{\sqrt{\frac 1 2 - \sqrt{\frac {1+ \sqrt u}8}} + \sqrt{\frac 1 2 - \sqrt{\frac {1+ \sqrt{1-u}}8}}}$$ is a constant.

Your equality is then obtained by obfuscating : multiply numerator and denominator with $\sqrt {2 \sqrt{2n+2}}$, and apply this with $u = \frac k {(n+1)^2}$

So the equality boils down to the original surprising equality about $cotan(a)$. I'm not sure if it can be understood geometrically.

You can get more complicated formulas (even more nested square roots !) by reflecting the angle around $a = \frac \pi {2^k}$ for $k > 4$

Comment: Nice answer! Many thanks.