# Find $\frac{\sum\limits^{2499}_{k=1}{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{50+\sqrt{k}}}}}{\sum\limits^{2499}_{k=1}{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{50+\sqrt{k}}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the ratio,$\frac{\sum\limits^{2499}_{k=1}{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{50+\sqrt{k}}}}}{\sum\limits^{2499}_{k=1}{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{50+\sqrt{k}}}}}$

Comment: mh it is a finite problem, I guess you aren't allowed to use computer algebra systems are you ?

Comment: Hint: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464346/why-does-this-ratio-of-sums-of-square-roots-equal-1-sqrt2-sqrt42-sqrt2-co