# square root / factor problem $(A/B)^{13} - (B/A)^{13}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let
$A=\sqrt{13+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{13+\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{13+\sqrt{3}}+\cdots+\sqrt{13+\sqrt{168}}$ and
$B=\sqrt{13-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{13-\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{13-\sqrt{3}}+\cdots+\sqrt{13-\sqrt{168}}$.

Evaluate $(\frac{A}{B})^{13}-(\frac{B}{A})^{13}$.

By Calculator, I have $\frac{A}{B}=\sqrt{2}+1$ and $\frac{B}{A}=\sqrt{2}-1$.

But, I don't know how. Has someone any idea about this.

Comment: Where did you encounter this beauty?

Comment: ^ I want to know that too

Comment: I'm not sure. It's the one of grade 9th math competition problem.

Comment: How did it get 10 votes in 37 minutes?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Because it's a fascinating/fun little problem? :)

Comment: @crash: Uninformative title with subjective difficulties qualifications? Question without showing any efforts? Those usually garner between two downvotes to two upvotes in a span of days. Certainly not 10 upvotes in less than an hour.

Comment: @AuthawichNarissayaporn Alright mate, thanks. I solved it and my answer is down there. But I must say, it's a cool one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila *Usually* is the problem in what you just wrote--the most upvoted questions on MSE are the ones that often get closed in the matter of minutes and garner downvotes themselves. I cannot explain the voting patterns of users here. I imagine what happened to most people, like myself, was they opened a question expecting to find a really easy precalc problem, but then it turned out to be something rather intriguing, hence the upvotes.

Comment: @HasanSaad Thank you. I still don't know the way this result comes.T_T

Comment: Well, the appropriate way is to comment on my answer so I can help you there. Tell me what part you're struggling with and I'll either edit my answer to clarify or explain to you in the comment

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for your opinion. Now, I just edited the name of title to make more informative. :D

Comment: here is more hard problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464346/why-does-this-ratio-of-sums-of-square-roots-equal-1-sqrt2-sqrt42-sqrt2-co?lq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This took me some time to solve. Here you go:

First, we find this:

$$\begin{aligned}
(\sqrt{13+\sqrt{a}}-\sqrt{13-\sqrt{a}})^2
&=13+\sqrt{a}+13-\sqrt{a}-2\sqrt{13+\sqrt{a}}\sqrt{13-\sqrt{a}}\\
&=2(13-\sqrt{169-a})
\end{aligned}$$

So,

$$\sqrt{13+\sqrt{a}}-\sqrt{13-\sqrt{a}}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{13-\sqrt{169-a}}$$

By what we have, we write,

$A-B=\sqrt{2}B$

What I used here is the fact that I've summed over all $a$ from $1$ to $168$, and that summing with $\sqrt{169-a}$ is the same as summing with $\sqrt{a}$ in this question.

Now, we have $A=(1+\sqrt{2})B$

Thus, $\frac{A}{B}=1+\sqrt{2}$ and $\frac{B}{A}=\sqrt{2}-1$

We just calculate $(\frac{A}{B})^{13}$ and $(\frac{B}{A})^{13}$ which I believe is okay to be done using calculator. Else, comment so I can edit my answer.

Comment: Nice work. But "which I believe is okay to be done using calculator"--can you show how to reach the integer solution $94642$ manually through algebraic manipulation?

Comment: I'll give it a try. Please wait a bit.

Comment: Cool. Will do. :) Because I think, @AuthawichNarissayaporn correct me if I'm wrong, that computing that is actually *part* of the problem.

Comment: I'm not really sure I can do it. The best way after my work is to use @math110 solution. He has it pretty nice there to be honest.

Comment: @HasanSaad How fascinating! thank you guy :)

Comment: I just checked the step-by-step solution offered by Wolfram|Alpha, and they seem to have simply brute-forced it--very hideous.

Comment: ^Wolfram noobs :p
@AuthawichNarissayaporn You're welcome mate. :)

Comment: What do you mean "Wolfram noobs"?

Comment: I meant they're noobs because they brute-forced it. :|

Comment: +1 Ah. I thought you meant I was a noob for using WA haha. Glad I got clarification first. ;)

Comment: No lol. I use WA all the time. :p

Comment: Alright cool. I'll stop cluttering up your post with comments now. Btw, really sexy solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180599/proving-that-the-number-sqrt37-sqrt50-sqrt37-5-sqrt2-is-r/1180612#1180612). +1

Comment: @HasanSaad I think the R.H.S of first equality maybe $13+\sqrt{a}+13-\sqrt{a}$. :D

Comment: What do you mean with R.H.S?

Comment: Right-hand side?

Comment: Oops, yeah. My bad, though the answer stays pretty valid. I'll fix it, sorry.

Comment: @crash $\frac{A}{B} = 1 + \sqrt 2 $ and $\frac{B}{A} =  - 1 + \sqrt 2 $ so ${\left( {\frac{A}{B}} \right)^{13}} - {\left( {\frac{B}{A}} \right)^{13}} = {\left( {1 + \sqrt 2 } \right)^{13}} - {\left( {1 - \sqrt 2 } \right)^{13}}$. Applying the binomial theorem and Pascal's triangle, the $\sqrt 2 $ diappears and we get ${\left( {\frac{A}{B}} \right)^{13}} - {\left( {\frac{B}{A}} \right)^{13}} = 2\sum\limits_{k = 0}^6 {{2^k}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{13}\\
{2k}
\end{array}} \right)} = 2 + 312 + 5720 + 27456 + 41184 + 18304 + 1664= 94642$.

Comment: @crash Sorry, I hit "enter" at the wrong time. Take another look at my message, which shows you how to get to 94642 by algebraic manipulation without using a calculator, as you asked for a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 5):

Let
$$A=\sum_{n=1}^{168}\sqrt{13+\sqrt{n}},B=\sum_{n=1}^{168}\sqrt{13-\sqrt{n}}$$
since
$$\sqrt{2}A=\sum_{n=1}^{168}\sqrt{26+2\sqrt{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{168}\left(\sqrt{13+\sqrt{169-n}}+\sqrt{13-\sqrt{169-n}}\right)=A+B$$ so we have $x=\dfrac{A}{B}=\sqrt{2}$,then we have
$$x=\sqrt{2}+1,\dfrac{1}{x}=\sqrt{2}-1\Longrightarrow x+\dfrac{1}{x}=2\sqrt{2}$$
let
$$a_{n}=x^n-x^{-n}$$ use this well know indentity
$$a_{n+2}=(x+\dfrac{1}{x})a_{n+1}-a_{n}\Longrightarrow a_{n+2}=2\sqrt{2}a_{n+1}-a_{n}$$
$$a_{1}=2,a_{2}=4\sqrt{2}$$
so 
$$a_{3}=2\sqrt{2}a_{2}-a_{1}=16-2=14$$
$$a_{4}=2\sqrt{2}a_{3}-a_{2}=28\sqrt{2}-4\sqrt{2}=24\sqrt{2}$$
$$a_{5}=2\sqrt{2}a_{4}-a_{3}=96-14=82$$
$$\cdots$$

Comment: But, without calculator, we don't know $x=\sqrt{2}+1$.

Comment: can see @Hasan Saad solution

Comment: Thank you for making a solution perfect :)