# Simplifying Fraction for Nested Radicals

Tags: alternative-proof, nested-radicals

A while back, a problem asked me to simplify the nested radical$$\dfrac{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{2}}+\dots+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{98}}+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{99}}}{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{2}}+\dots+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{98}}+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{99}\sqrt{10-\sqrt{k}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{99}\sqrt{10+\sqrt{k}}}$$

This problem can be simply solved using the idea that $$\sqrt{m-\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{m+\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{2}\times \sqrt{m+\sqrt{m^2-n}}$$

Which implies that $$\sum_{k=1}^{99}\sqrt{10-\sqrt{k}}+\sum_{k=1}^{99}\sqrt{10+\sqrt{k}}=\sqrt{2}\sum_{k=1}^{99}\sqrt{10+\sqrt{100-k}}$$
Thus we get that $$\sum_{k=1}^{99}\sqrt{10-\sqrt{k}}=(\sqrt{2}-1)\times \sum_{k=1}^{99}\sqrt{10+\sqrt{k}}$$

Thus the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}=\sqrt{2}+1$.

However, it took me a long time to find this solution. In truth, the solution above seems rather lucky.

Also, it was actually hard to believe the value was $\sqrt{2}+1$, which seemed to have nothing to do with the number $10$ itself.

Is there a more intuitive/alternate approach to this problem?

Comment: Indeed, the same proof shows that for *any* integer $k\ge2$,$$\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{k^2-1} \sqrt{k+\sqrt j}}{\sum_{j=1}^{k^2-1} \sqrt{k-\sqrt j}} = \sqrt2+1.$$Which kind of freaks me out...!

Comment: @GregMartin Unless I am mistaken, it works for _any real_ number that is of the form $\sqrt{m}$ where $m$ is larger than $2$. I found that very strange also....Is there some intuitive way to think of this?

Comment: Note that $m$ is a natural number in my above comment.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464346/why-does-this-ratio-of-sums-of-square-roots-equal-1-sqrt2-sqrt42-sqrt2-co) and [the answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/484881/78967).