# Value of $AB^{-1}$ Given $A,B$ are in square root expression

Tags: contest-math

> If $\displaystyle A = \sum^{n^2-1}_{k=1}\sqrt{\sqrt{2n}+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}}$ and $\displaystyle B = \sum^{n^2-1}_{k=1}\sqrt{\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}}$, Then $\displaystyle A\cdot B^{-1} = $

Try:   Iam trying to convert  $A+B$ into $A$ or in $B$ form like this way $$\bigg(\sqrt{\sqrt{2n}+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}}\bigg)^2=2\sqrt{2n}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}}$$
$$\bigg(\sqrt{\sqrt{2n}+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}}\bigg)=\sqrt{2}\bigg(\sqrt{\sqrt{2n}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}}}\bigg)$$

could some help me to solve further, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this ratio of sums of square roots equal $1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{4+2\sqrt2}=\cot\frac\pi{16}$ for any natural number $n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464346/why-does-this-ratio-of-sums-of-square-roots-equal-1-sqrt2-sqrt42-sqrt2-co)

Comment: @mathlove mindblowing result

Comment: You should explicitly mention that $n\in\mathbb N$.